# show div as per radio button value in database

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Open a div on based on database radio button  value.  if value is male in database then show For male and if value is female in database then show Female male

```
$status = isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : '';

                <input type="radio" name="status" value="male" checked="checked">male<br>
                <input type="radio" name="status" value="female">female<br>

<div class="1">For male</div>
<div class="2">Female male</div>
```

Comment: just put condition and based on that show div.

Comment: `$_POST['status']` are from database or form value?

Comment: @VinayKaklotar $_POST['status'] is for database value is male and female

Comment: So you can do using `if` condition!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right this will do the trick

```
    $status = isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : '';

if ($status == "male") {
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="male" checked="checked">male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="female">female<br>
}elseif ($status == "female") {
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="male">male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="female" checked="checked">female<br>
}else {
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="male">male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="female">female<br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add if condition

```
   $status = isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : ''; ?>
   <input type="radio" name="status" value="male" <?php echo $status=='male'?  'checked="checked"':''?>>male<br>
   <input type="radio" name="status" value="female" <?php echo $status=='female'? 'checked="checked"':''?>>female<br>
   <?php if($status=='male') { ?>
   <div class="1">For male</div>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php if($status=='female') { ?>
   <div class="2">For Female</div>
   <?php } ?>
```